# Why are we using RunOnUiThread in the app

Tags: android, xamarin

I am new to android and I have a question, it looks silly but i need to know.
I was looking in a source code of an open project that was uploaded in git the app starts with an authentication activity
user enters his/her username password, and if it didn't exists in database, it will show a snack bar, but if it was exist in database the app will do this:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => { TransitToServiceListActivity();});
```

and in `TransitToServiceListActivity()` method, the code defines a new intent and starts navigate to the activity related to that intent.

So my question is, why in the first place we didn't start to navigate to other Activities.

why we need to do first:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => { TransitToServiceListActivity();});
```

and then star to navigate between activities?

Why not create an intent from that activity we are going to transit to, and call that activity
what problem this `RunOnUiThread(() => { TransitToServiceListActivity();});` solves that we are using it?

Comment: You can't call UI from another thread than the UI thread. `runOnUiThread`takes care of switching threads. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of [RunOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) is to ensure that a given [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) is executed in the UI thread.

So, the method **RunOnUiThread** is meant to be called when running in a different thread other than the main one, and it is required that some specific code gets executed in the main thread. Although is also perfectly valid to be called in an ambiguous code block, which could be called in both the UI thread or a background thread, for which scenario RunOnUiThread will resolve if the runnable must be executed immediately or passed to the main thread.

I am guessing that probably the code you are looking at, is performing the authentication in a background thread. If it doesn't and there is no chance that the authentication is never executed in a background thread, then there is no point to use RunOnUiThread.